# Surveys for mobile- from UX point of view is it better to implement questions on 1 scrollable landing page or 1 question-1 page flow?

Tags: mobile, surveys, flow

Currently, I'm redesigning the survey and I'm looking for any use case/research in which flow increases completion rates. Does someone have any insights?

Comment: What is your use-case? I reckon the two approaches tackle different business needs. Could you expand a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Depends
Both are great, and solve the user problem
I thinking you should use a scrollable landing page, when you have a question with similar context and could group them.

You can use a page flow, when the questions doesn't have a similar context.

Answer (score 0):

If you are filling some "Form" alike it's better to use a scrolling page. But if it is for a survey/question, I rather choose 1 question-1 page (with a progress bar) it encourages the user to more focused on filling the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I use questions on 1 page, because I have an interviewer who can skip questions and choose which ones to voice.

[image]